# How to test if a dictionary (in an external file) contains the user inputted username (Python3 )?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am building a Flea Market program. I have an external file hosting all the usernames and passwords of employees. I am trying to test the login section, asking for username then password. It tests if the UN is in the dictionary contained in the readline().

Here is the external file with the usernames and passwords. :

```
managers = {"manager":"password", "owner":"apple"}
employees = {"jane":"none", "john":"banana"}
```

And here is the code.:

```
print("Welcome to Flea Master 2000...\n")
read_employee_file = open('employees_list.txt', 'r')
managers = read_employee_file.readline(0)
employees = read_employee_file.readline(1)
print(managers)
read_employee_file.close()

user_id = input("User ID:\n")
user_password = input('Password:\n')
if user_id in managers[:]:
    if managers[user_id] == user_password:
        print("Welcome, {0}.".format (user_id))
        user_status='manager'
if user_id in employees:
    if employees[user_id] == user_password:
        print("Welcome, {0}".format (user_id))
        user_status = 'staff'
if user_status == 'manager':
    action_manager = int(input("Options: (Input number to select...)\n1) Add employee.\n2) Remove employee.\n"))
    if action_manager == 1:
        employee_addition_type=input("What kind of employee is he/she? ('manager' or 'staff')")
        if employee_addition_type == 'manager':
            new_manager_username = input("Enter the new manager's username...\n")
            new_manager_password = input("Enter the new manager's password...\n")
            managers[new_manager_username] = new_manager_password
        else:
            new_staff_username = input("Enter the new staff member's username...\n")
            new_staff_password = input("Enter the new staff member's password...\n")
            employees[new_staff_username]=new_staff_password

    if action_manager == 2:
        print("The list of current employees is: \n")
        for key in all_staff:
            print(key)
        print('\n')
        which_remove = input("Now, which do you want to remove? Enter the username exactly.\n")
        if which_remove in managers:
            del managers[which_remove]
        else:
            del employees[which_remove]
        print("\nDone. Updated roster is:\n")
        all_staff = dict(managers, **employees)
        for key in all_staff:
            print(key
                  )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. +1 for including a short, complete program that demonstrates your question. (Although, you could have made your sample program much shorter.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify better the problem you have, including scenarios where you have such problem (I can guess an error in your code but perhaps it is not related and you fixed it).

Comment: Colby, did you choose the format of the external username/password file, or was it specified as part of your assignment?

Comment: Rob, I chose it. Feel free to change the format.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to read and parse your input file. Assuming your file is the way you specified and you are willing to handle the exceptions, here is one sample method for you. You need to handle exceptions approriately.

```
try:
    #This will read your in.conf which contains user/pwds in the dictionary format you specified.
    #Read documentation on exec here: 
       # https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#exec
    with open('in.conf') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            exec(line)
    user_id = input("User ID:\n")
    user_password = input('Password:\n')
    if user_id in managers and user_password == managers[user_id]:
        print("Welcome, {0}.".format (user_id))
        user_status='manager'
    elif user_id in employees and user_password == employees[user_id]:
        print("Welcome, {0}.".format (user_id))
        user_status='staff'
    else:
        print "invalid credentials"
except NameError:
    #catch situations where your file doesn't contain managers or employees dictionary
    #I just raise it so you can see what it would print
    raise
except:
    #other exceptions as you see appropriate to handle ....
    #I just raise it so you can see what it would print
    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `readline` lines are a bit incorrect. The argument to `readlines` is the maximum number of bytes it will read. So `readlines(6)` doesn't mean "read the sixth line", it means "read no more than six characters from the current line". I suggest just doing `read_employee_file.readline()`, with no argument.

```
managers = read_employee_file.readline()
employees = read_employee_file.readline()
```

Now you have the full contents of each line, but both variables are still strings. However, you could use the `json` module to load those dictionaries.

```
import json
line = 'managers = {"manager":"password", "owner":"apple"}'

#chop off the left part of the string containing "managers = "
line = line.partition(" = ")[2]
d = json.loads(line)

print "the owner's password is", d["owner"]

if "bob" not in d:
    print "can't find bob's password in managers dictionary!"
```

Result:

```
the owner's password is apple
can't find bob's password in managers dictionary!
```